# How to recover lost partition and files after installation of Ubuntu on Windows partition?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I have got a laptop from one my friend which has installed Ubuntu by choosing a wrong option and has re-partitioned the entire hard drive and has lost all his private files.

I booted the laptop by a live Linux CD and I can see 4 partitions. First, one system partition 1,86 GB NTFS, then 2 X 46.5GB for Ubuntu and lastly a 603GB unallocated partition.

He doesn't need to keep Ubuntu just wants to back his files as there are crucial. I know some parts of data have been overwritten but wondering if there is a way that I can recover the data?

Answer (score 2):

Try using testdisk through a liveDVD or liveUSB.

Install it `sudo apt-get install testdisk`. Then try recover **partition**.

Next time backup your data before doing anyhing that important and risky as installing an operating system.

Comment: Backup your data *regularly* or sooner or later *something* will eat it, and it probably won't be something you expected to.